# Azure ARM deployment, passing dynamic variables from powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, continuous-deployment, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have created an ARM template to deploy a service with a set of application settings. 
One of my parameters in the ARM template does not have a default value. 
At present, when I run the deployment script using ISE I am asked "Supply values for the following parameters:" (a request for human input).

This is fine but this script will be automated. How do I pipe this dynamic variable into this field?

ARM:

```
"Paramters":{
    "dynamicParam": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "dont know this until deployment"
        }
    }
}
```

The deployment powershell is boiler plate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several ways to do that, easiest one is this:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment ... -dynamicParam value
```

another one (which is cooler) is to create a hash table with the values of parameters you have and splat it against the cmdlet:

```
$params = @{
   paramA = "test"
   paramB = "anotherTest"
}
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment ... @params
```

Another way is to preprocess the json parameters file and pass it to the deployment

Comment: As simple as that! I will really have to work on my google search terms. Thank you - really trying to hit these issues in this new world face on. Testing it out now.

Comment: no problem, remember to accept the answer if it helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add to above answer use -TemplateParameterObject to pass $params

`New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $deploymentName -TemplateFile $templateFilePath -TemplateParameterObject $params;`

Answer (score -2):

There is simplest and right way to pass dynamic argument in Az powershell while you create resource deployment through ARM templates .

Kindly use the below cmdlet to achieve that.

```
az group deployment create --name TempGroup --resource-group insightsrg --parameters '{\"actionGroupName\": {\"value\": \"jsonActionGroup\"},\"actionGroupShortName\": {\"value\": \"JAG\"}}' --template-file "C:\HM\ARM\policy\actiongroup\actiongroup.json"
```